# private String method error, issues with getting the correct user input

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty with writing a Java program, in particular with the enterCustomerName method. I have used String so that I can get worded input from the user. There are other errors, but this one I don't understand. I'm new to Java programming, so any help is greatly appreciated.

It's a program for a fruit and vegetable store.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FruitVegShop

{


    private void printWelcomeMessage()
    { // print the welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to Rocky Fruit and Vegetable Market");
    }


    private String enterCustomerName()
    { // prompt for, read and return a customer name
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the customer's name: ");
        String customerName;
        customerName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("Hello %s\n", customerName);
        return "";
    }


    private String enterProduceName()
    { // prompt for, read and return the name of the produce
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the produce");
        String name;
        name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("P: %s\n", name);
        return "";
    }


    private void printPurchaseNumber(int purchaseNumber)
    { // print the number of the purchase

    }


    private double enterProduceWeight(String name)
    { // prompt for, read and return the weight of the produce
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the weight of the produce: ");
        double weight;
        weight = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("Produce Weight: %d\n", weight);
        return 0;
    }


    private double enterProduceCost(String name)
    { // prompt for, read and return the cost of the produce
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of the produce: ");
        double costPerKg;
        costPerKg = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("Produce Price: $%d\n", costPerKg);
        return 0;
    }


    private void printPurchase(String name, double weight, double costPerKg, double cost)
    { // print the details of one pruchase

    double produceTotal;

    System.out.println("Produce:");
    System.out.printf("Produce: %d\n", name);
    System.out.printf("Weight (kg): %d\n", weight);
    System.out.printf("@ $%d.2\n /kg", costPerKg);
    System.out.printf("TOTAL: $%d.2\n", produceTotal); // ERROR: variable produceTotal might not have been initialized

    produceTotal = weight * costPerKg;

    }


    private boolean discount(String name)
    { // determine if the customer is eligle for a discount and return true or false
        if(


        return scannerObject.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase(“y”);
    }


    private void printTotalCost(String name, int numberOfPurchases, double cost, boolean discount)
    { // print the total cost of the order and discount information if neccessary
    }


    private void printExitMessage(String name)
    { // print the exit message
    }


    private void processCustomer()
    { // process one customer's order
        String customerName,        // the name of the customer
                produceName;        // the name of the produce

        double produceWeight,       // the weight ofthe produce
                produceCostPerKg,   // the cost per kilo of the produce
                purchaseCost,       // the cost of the purchase
                totalCost = 0;      // the total cost of the order

        int purchaseNumber = 0;     // the number of the current purchase

        boolean discount;           // boolean to say if customer is eligible for a discount

        printWelcomeMessage();      // print the title message

        customerName = enterCustomerName(); // get the customer name

        purchaseNumber++;                                   // increment the number of the purchase
        printPurchaseNumber(purchaseNumber);                // print the number of the purchase
        produceName = enterProduceName();                   // get the name of the produce item
        produceWeight = enterProduceWeight(produceName);    // get the weight of the purchase
        produceCostPerKg = enterProduceCost(produceName);   // get the cost per kg

        purchaseCost = produceWeight * produceCostPerKg;    // calculate the cost of the purchase
        totalCost += purchaseCost;                          // add to total cost

        printPurchase(produceName, produceWeight, produceCostPerKg, purchaseCost); // print the purchase details

        discount = discount(customerName);  // determine if the customer is eligible for a discount

        printTotalCost(customerName, purchaseNumber, totalCost, discount); // print the total cost

        printExitMessage(customerName); // print the final exit message
    }


    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        FruitVegShop fruitVegShop = new FruitVegShop();

        fruitVegShop.processCustomer();
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```js
Welcome to Rocky Fruit and Vegetable Market
Please enter the customer's name:
Anonymous
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
        at FruitVegShop.enterCustomerName(FruitVegShop.java:20)
        at FruitVegShop.processCustomer(FruitVegShop.java:102)
        at FruitVegShop.main(FruitVegShop.java:127)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

```js
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FruitVegShop

{


 private void printWelcomeMessage()
 { // print the welcome message
 System.out.println("                Welcome to Rocky Fruit and Vegetable Market");
 }


 private String enterCustomerName()
 { // prompt for, read and return a customer name
  Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the name of the customer ==> ");
  String customerName;
  customerName = in.nextLine();
     return customerName;
 }


 private String enterProduceName()
 { // prompt for, read and return the name of the produce
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the name of the produce ==> ");
  String produceName;
  produceName = in.nextLine();
  return produceName;
 }


 private void printPurchaseNumber(int purchaseNumber)
 { // print the number of the purchase
  int counter = 0;
  while ( counter <= 3 ) // loop the order 3 times
 
 }


 private double enterProduceWeight(String name)
 { // prompt for, read and return the weight of the produce
  Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.printf("Enter the weight (kg) of the %s\n ==> ", produceName);
  double produceWeight;
  produceWeight = in.nextDouble();
  return produceWeight;
 }


 private double enterProduceCost(String name)
 { // prompt for, read and return the cost of the produce
  Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.printf("Enter the cost per kg of the %s\n ==> ", produceName);
  double produceCostPerKg;
  produceCostPerKg = in.nextDouble();
  return produceCostPerKg;
 }


 private void printPurchase(String produceName, double produceWeight, double produceCostPerKg, double cost)
 { // print the details of one pruchase

 double produceCost;

 System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
 System.out.printf("%f\n of %s\n at $%.2f\n per kg is $%.2f\n", produceWeight, produceName, produceCostPerKg, produceCost);
 System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");

 produceCost = produceWeight * produceCostPerKg;

 }


 private boolean discount(String name)
 { // determine if the customer is eligle for a discount and return true or false
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  if (in.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
   return true;
  else
            return false;
 }


 private void printTotalCost(String name, int numberOfPurchases, double cost, boolean discount)
 { // print the total cost of the order and discount information if neccessary

  double totalCost;
  double discountValue;

  System.out.println("**********************************************************************");
  System.out.printf("%s\n the total for %d\n fruit and vegetable purchases is $%.2f\n", customerName, purchaseNumber, totalCost);
  System.out.printf("This includes a discount of $%.2d\n", discountValue);
  System.out.println("**********************************************************************");

  // make a addition counter for the order.
  // set a discount value
 }


 private void printExitMessage(String name)
 { // print the exit message
  System.out.printf("Thank you %s\n for shopping at the Rocky Fruit and Vegetable Market", customerName);
  System.out.println("Written by s0270780");
 }


 private void processCustomer()
 { // process one customer's order
  String customerName,  // the name of the customer
    produceName;  // the name of the produce

  double produceWeight,  // the weight of the produce
    produceCostPerKg, // the cost per kilo of the produce
    purchaseCost,  // the cost of the purchase
    totalCost = 0;  // the total cost of the order

  int purchaseNumber = 0;  // the number of the current purchase

  boolean discount;   // boolean to say if customer is eligible for a discount

  printWelcomeMessage();  // print the title message

  customerName = enterCustomerName(); // get the customer name

  purchaseNumber++;         // increment the number of the purchase
  printPurchaseNumber(purchaseNumber);    // print the number of the purchase
  produceName = enterProduceName();     // get the name of the produce item
  produceWeight = enterProduceWeight(produceName); // get the weight of the purchase
  produceCostPerKg = enterProduceCost(produceName); // get the cost per kg

  purchaseCost = produceWeight * produceCostPerKg; // calculate the cost of the purchase
  totalCost += purchaseCost;       // add to total cost

  printPurchase(produceName, produceWeight, produceCostPerKg, purchaseCost); // print the purchase details

  discount = discount(customerName); // determine if the customer is eligible for a discount

  printTotalCost(customerName, purchaseNumber, totalCost, discount); // print the total cost

  printExitMessage(customerName); // print the final exit message
 }


 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
  FruitVegShop fruitVegShop = new FruitVegShop();

  fruitVegShop.processCustomer();
 }
}
```

```js
C:\Users\Jockman\Desktop\The Fruit & Veg Shop\FruitVegShop.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.printf("Enter the weight (kg) of the %f\n ==> ", produceName);
                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable produceName
  location: class FruitVegShop
C:\Users\Jockman\Desktop\The Fruit & Veg Shop\FruitVegShop.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.printf("Enter the cost per kg of the %s\n ==> ", produceName);
                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable produceName
  location: class FruitVegShop
C:\Users\Jockman\Desktop\The Fruit & Veg Shop\FruitVegShop.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.printf("%s\n the total for %d\n fruit and vegetable purchases is $%.2f\n", customerName, purchaseNumber, totalCost);
                                                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable customerName
  location: class FruitVegShop
C:\Users\Jockman\Desktop\The Fruit & Veg Shop\FruitVegShop.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.printf("%s\n the total for %d\n fruit and vegetable purchases is $%.2f\n", customerName, purchaseNumber, totalCost);
                                                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable purchaseNumber
  location: class FruitVegShop
C:\Users\Jockman\Desktop\The Fruit & Veg Shop\FruitVegShop.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.printf("Thank you %s\n for shopping at the Rocky Fruit and Vegetable Market", customerName);
                                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable customerName
  location: class FruitVegShop
5 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? And can you post the error stack?

Comment: Hi krisdestruction, I've added it to the post, and thank you Elliot and Tony, that's really helped me out.

Comment: I've restarted the code, now working with the third code in the post, and now I can't even get it to produce a .class file for it. I've updated the main code, and the error log beneath the third code is what I get.

Comment: Having problems with the answer? [Please comment there.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) Having another question? [You will get better help by asking it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to return the `name` instead of `""` in `enterCustomerName()` and `enterProduceName()` change

```
return "";
```

to

```
return customerName;
```

and

```
return name;
```

respectively. Also, `enterProduceWeight` and `enterProduceCost` should not `return 0;` but should `return weight;` and `return costPerKg;` (if you want them to print as non empty and not `0` in `printPurchase`).